# Will a Dell Inspiron 1525 laptop work without a battery?

Tags: power-supply, battery, dell-inspiron

If you remove the battery from the 1525 and use only the power adapter, will the laptop work? Or does it need the battery in there for it to turn on?

I'm looking for authoritative answers with some explanation, practical experience, or a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does. I've just tested mine, and all's fine.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, it will work. All laptops I have ever used, including several models of Dell Inspirons, work fine with the battery removed. The circuitry is designed such that you can run it off of A/C power. It is actually recommended that if you use a laptop as a desktop replacement, that you remove the battery and run it on A/C power only, because this helps preserve the life of the battery. The only concern is if the plug gets knocked out, then you have an unexpected shutdown, but if you're careful you'll be fine.

Answer (score -1):

you sould use the UPS as possible, and with the battery remine in the laptop. Now, the laptops have it own cycle to Control charging and discharging, and avoid over charging and dis charging. the battery will be recharged when 90% or 95%, when you use the UPS, the battry natural discharging is very little. You won't need to worry about the battery will be charged and dis charged frequently. 
With the battery in is good for your laptop when there is unexpected power outages, and there will no hurt to your battery. Contrary, it's bad for batteries to storing them for a long long time without using.
though the battety is expensives, but compare to the laptop, the battery is much cheaper. Without batteris is bad for the laptop when unexpected power outages. storing battery for a long long time has no batter to preserve the life of the battery.

laptop-batteries.htm

www.

you may find something you need

Comment: Had trouble reading this because of the spelling/grammar mistakes.